# How to use populated data in condition in node.js, mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pagination

I am using this query to get data.

```
   let query = User.find({$and:
                    [{isDeleted:{$ne:true}}, 
                    {company_domain:req.headers.domain}]
                    });
    var populateQuery = [{path: 'created_by'}];
    var options = {
        limit: parseInt(req.query.limit),
        page: parseInt(req.query.page),
        populate: populateQuery,
    };

        query.exec(()=>{
        User.paginate(query, options).then(function(result) {
                res.json(result);
            });
```

I want to filter data from the populated property `created_by`; for example I like to filter data by `created_by.name` How can I do that?

Comment: Question was edited, hence the different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counts will not appear in results because of the way javascript executes code.It won't wait for your User counts to be fetched and then return the response, instead the following lines are being executed before the counts are actually fetched and that's why response has no count in it.

```
result.activeCount=a;
result.deactiveCount=b;
res.json(result);
```

Change your code with following:

```
 var results = {};
 User.paginate(query, options)
      .then(function(records) {
            results.records = records;
            return User.count({status: 'Active'}).exec();      
        })
      .then(function(activeCount){
           results.activeCount =  activeCount; 
           return User.count({status: 'Deactive'}).exec();
       })
      .then(function(deactiveCount){
           results.deactiveCount = deactiveCount;
           // finally here send the response.
           res.json(results);
       });
```

Here I'm using Promises to first fetch the records and add it in the `results` object inside first `then` and from there I'm returning another Promise object of `User.count` which will be handled in next chained `then` method. In this second `then` method I'm adding `activeCount` to the results and returning another Promise of `User.count` which is going to be handled in next chained `then` method. In this final third `then` method, I'm adding `deactiveCount` in `results` objects and finally sending back the response.

> Note: Read more about JavaScript Sync and Async and code execution.